# path for cq.foundation-main library in aem

Tags: aem

i am looking for cq.foundation-main client library path.
I would like to disable granite.jquery client lib on aem 6.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **DISCLAIMER**: I would not disable granite.jquery clientlib as it is a dependency for many other clientlibs and might break the UI in your AEM instance. **Do this at your own risk.**

here is the answer to your question:

to find the location of any clientlib, you can go to: http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html

then search for the clientlib category, in your case: `cq.foundation-main` and the path will be listed.

on my 6.3 instances, that path is `/etc/clientlibs/foundation/main`

Comment: you are correct. application has contexthub code and it is breaking when i take out data-sly-call for cq-foundation-main in headlibs.html